# What bank angles are used for IFR operations?

Tags: instrument-flight-rules

ICAO requires or recommends 25 degrees bank angle. On Boeing auto pilot it's possible to set 30 degrees to be used. What bank angles usually are used for Holding, ILS intercept en-route when flying manually and on autopilot? Any EASA rules in this field?